# Angular: function call as attribute value for directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, using-directives

This is a reduction of my directive:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    template:
      '<form name="form" action="{{action}}" method="post" target="_blank">' +
        '<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="{{itemname}}">' +
      '</form>',
    scope: {
      action: '@action',
      itemname: '@itemname',
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.action = attrs.action || 'http://www.example.com';
      scope.itemname = attrs.itemname();
    }
  };
});
```

and I use it this way:

```
<div ng-if="itemWasSelected">
  <my-directive
     action="{{ 'http://www.example.com' }}"
     itemname="itemNameBuildFunction"
  />
</div>
```

In my controller, I have:

```
$scope.itemNameBuildFunction = function() {
  return $scope.value1 + $scope.value2;
};
```

I would expect my directive, when it is linked (it is inside an `ng-if` clause, so, I mean, when the `ng-if` condition evaluates to true), to call `attrs.itemname()` $scope function, to assign scope.itemname variable in the controller's link function.

Instead, what I get is the error:

```
TypeError: attrs.itemname is not a function
```

Can you please give me some directions? As you can see, I'm quite confused, with angular directives... :-(

Comment: Have you closed the directive </my-directive> and also try scope.itemname = attrs.itemname;

Comment: what is this function `attrs.itemname()`? never saw it defined... also if it was defined as a function attrs convert into JSON objects. so you would have to use angular.fromJson(attrs.itemname)

Comment: @MandeepSingh: first advise: thanks, just corrected my answer; second advise: that way, in the produced form I get the string: `itemname`, which is not what I expect... :-(

Comment: @Zargold: `attrs.itemname` contains a string (`itemNameBuildFunction`) which is a $scope function name...

Comment: @MandeepSingh: no, it is not: I get the **function name**, and not the evaluated function result... :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need this statement `attrs.itemname()`.

Your function reference passed in directive  is bind to to the variable `itemname` on `scope` that is passed as first parameter in `link` function which `isolated scope`

Just change the statement from

```
scope.itemname = attrs.itemname();
```

To :

```
scope.itemname();  // this will call the function `itemNameBuildFunction`
```

EDIT :

You have used `@` operator ofr binding function which is used in case passing primitive or object.You are passing function, so , you should use `&` operator,will evaluate as function.

```
scope: {
      action: '@action',
      itemname: '&itemname',
    }
```

EDIT 2: 
Yous should passed function `itemNameBuildFunction()` and not `itemNameBuildFunction`

```
<my-directive action="{{ 'http://www.example.com' }}" 
    itemname="itemNameBuildFunction()" />
```

Working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/wuU6rfnZ0OrNoguSqGwj?p=preview)

Comment: @Zargold What  is wrong?Can u elaborate or fixed it and what is duplicate

Comment: Duplicate means: Someone else answered the exact same thing 2 minutes before you did. Wrong means: It seems like the person asking the question does have a function for itemname but he didn't define it in the right place or something though can't be sure.

Comment: `scope.itemname()` produces: `TypeError: scope.itemname is not a function`

Comment: man first thing please check the right answer and mine one.Please check what duplicate you find there.Second one `attrs.itemname` will not evalute to expression that is why there is isolated scope is used.That is why is stating such error

Comment: I **need** an isolated scope.

Comment: @MarcoS you already defined isolated scope.Just need to call it on `scope` like `scope.itemname()` and it will call `itemNameBuildFunction ` function

Comment: As I already told, `scope.itemname()` produces: `TypeError: scope.itemname is not a function`

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I did change `itemname: '@itemname'` to `itemname: '&itemname`, but `scope.itemname` is always a string, in my directive link function, so I can't *call* it... :-(

Comment: It is unrecommended to use `<MyDirective />` use <MyDirective></MyDirective>

Comment: Thanks for your plunker, RIYAJ... It seems to reproduce my use case... I even added an `ng-if` clause around directive (here: https://plnkr.co/edit/oyn3UWjbBw6BI63i7Qqk?p=preview), and it keeps working. Unfortunately, I can't apply your solution to my use case... :-( As soon as I can I'll accept your answer!

Comment: OK looks a lot better and not a duplicate anymore great work.

Comment: I +1'd you just it looks like he may have really needed to call the function in the controller.

Comment: Thanks... The problem was I were using `action`, which seems to clash with form's `action`... :-). Changed `action` to `actionValue`, everything works for me, too, THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you actually want `'='` type which will take in javascript objects and (without requiring JSON.parse) allow you to use them in your scope. A function is javascript object which can be run using the ();

So the best solution is:
`scope: {
      action: '@',
      itemname: '=',
    },`

This will allow you to take a callback for the item name and then run it in the scope as you see fit.

https://plnkr.co/edit/cKzLhP4SwHey266Flr5w?p=preview.

Also, how would someone submit the form you offer? It doesn't seem to make sense you should have a `<input type='submit'/>` if you want to submit a hidden input name. Also, you probably want to use templateURL and include an HTML template instead of having a big dynamic form in you js.